# NextJS & Radio Button Shadcn

Tags: next.js, shadcnui

I am trying to push the size into the url but when I wrap the element in Link component the radio button isn't got checked.

```
<RadioGroup
        defaultValue={product.productSizes[0].id}
        className="flex items-center"
        name="size"
      >
        {product.productSizes.map((size) => (
          <div key={size.id} className="flex items-center">
           <Link href={`?size=${size.size.name}}`>
            <Label
              htmlFor={size.id}
              className="p-2 border cursor-pointer flex items-center space-x-2 rounded-lg"
            >
              <RadioGroupItem
                value={size.id}
                id={size.id}
                disabled={size.stock === 0}
                formAction={changeSize}
              />
              <span
                className={cn("leading-none uppercase", {
                  "text-muted-foreground": size.stock === 0,
                })}
              >
                {size.size.name}
              </span>
            </Label>
           </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
</RadioGroup>
```

I tried to move the wrappers around all elements and didn't work